# Output wanted on another place

Tags: java, bluej

I want my output at last, but my program is giving it after every entry. Please tell me what changes should I make! My program sorts out all the negative numbers entered by the user from a maximum of ten numbers.
My program is:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Task_3
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        double a, b;
        InputStreamReader read= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(read);
        for(a=1;a<=10;a++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your number");
            b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            if(b<0)
            {
                System.out.println(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result being shown on output screen:

```
Enter your number
5
Enter your number
6
Enter your number
1
Enter your number
45
Enter your number
874
Enter your number
-547
-547.0
Enter your number
-8
-8.0
Enter your number
-1
-1.0
Enter your number
-5
-5.0
Enter your number
6
```

Comment: Your program does not sort numbers

Comment: you want to see all numbers< that are less than 0?

Comment: to ankit rustagi: "sorts out"= removes, not sorts

Comment: do you want to report the positive numbers somewhere else? if so, just pass it as an argument to a function "report(b);" in an else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all numbers less than 0 to be displayed at the end, store them in an array

```
    double[] arr = new double[10];
    int count=-1;
    for(a=1;a<=10;a++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        if(b<0)
        {
            arr[++count] = b;
        }
    }
    for(a=1;a<=count;a++) System.out.println(arr[a]);
```

Answer (score 0):

make so:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Task_3
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {

        InputStreamReader read= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(read);
        double[] numMass = new double[10];
        int count = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a < 10; a ++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your number");
            double b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            if(b < 0)
            {
                numMass[count] = b;
                count++;    
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(numMass[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not compile as `numMass` has no dimensions. The array is also never printed.

Comment: fixed) I forget about printing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first read 10 numbers from standard input, and then afterwards print them together, then you have to first store the numbers using e.g. an `ArrayList` and then print them out separately.

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    double a, b;
    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStreamReader read= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(read);
    for(a=1;a<=10;a++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        b=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        if(b<0)
        {
            numbers.add(b); // Store number in list.
        }
    }
    for (Double d : numbers) { // Print out the numbers.
        System.out.println(d + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the filtered numbers only you can use a StringBuilder to compose the output and print it on the screen after the input mode has ended:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (/* your for loop) {
    /* your input logic */
    if (b < ) {
        result.append(b + "\n");
    }
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

If you have to perform additional processing of the result (and need Double format for that), use the following snipped:

```
List<Double> result = new LinkedList<>();
/* same as above instead, BUT */
      result.add(b);
/* ... */

for (Double d : result) {
     /* do your processing of the result here */
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a `LinkedList` for something as trivial as this, use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Snps I think it depends on what we are doing with the result list afterwards. `LinkedList` has complexity of `O(1)` for inserting. `ArrayList` has in most cases `O(1)` but `O(n)` in worst case.

Comment: In this case you are adding to end of list and iterating over all elements which is `O(1)` respective `O(n)` for both list types. The `ArrayList` might however outperform the `LinkedList`, even under optimal conditions for the `LinkedList`, because of higher memory locality (much more compact data structure). The `LinkedList` will also take up at least 4X more space. A `LinkedList` should never be used in the general case IMHO.